# Exporting project with libraries to runnable jar from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I was trying to export a test of a game I am working on(that uses the Slick library), to send to my partners who lack any IDE, all went well with the export in eclipse, but when I try to run it from command prompt, this is what I get in return.

```
C:\Users\Noah\Desktop>java -jar test.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:141)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)

        at org.nor.Main.main(Main.java:16)
        ... 5 more

C:\Users\Noah\Desktop>
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

NOTE: The project runs perfectly fine in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on a "get started" guide on slick if you are going to use it. Slick has several dependencies who use dll's to communicate with opengl. You need to specify where those dll's are kept so these dependencies can load the dll's. I found [this](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php?id=native_libraries) link that might help you do that..

Comment: I tried this, but when I inserted the code provided, I get the error `File can not be resolved to a type.` No suggestions. Any idea as to what is wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, imported java.io and worked like a charm, thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You also need the native lwjgl library and point to it.  The Export Jar functionality do not handle this.

Read up on the lwjgl manual for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your jars either to:

- the classpath in your java invocation
- the Manifest.mf of your main jar

Java won't automatically load your jars until they are in one of these locations.

Answer (score 0):

Try with File -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export

Comment: Tried this, I assumed you are supposed to build after selecting all, still same error.